# Add dynamic property to .NET classes

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Is it possible to add my own custom property to any type of object?

In this example the object is List but I mean for any kind of object (.NET or custom ones).

For example extend `List<string>` to add an extra property called `MyProperty`:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.MyProperty = "some value";
```

then call a method `ProcessList(List<string> list)`:

```
ProcessList(myList);

public void ProcessList(List<string> list)
{
  // get the custom property value

  string myprop = list.MyProperty.ToString();
  ....................
  do other work
}
```

Comment: Not exactly, but something similar is [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx)

Comment: Not really, but you could wrap a `List<T>` with your own type that has your properties.

Comment: No C# doesn't support "extension properties". what do you want that for?

Comment: Than I guess I have to implement my own custom type inheriting the target object add my custom properties and use my custom type instead ...

Answer (score 1):

No.  There is no "extension property" implementation in .NET.  Extension methods are more of a compiler trick, and only work as static methods because they do not require their own state (at least should not).

A property would require a backing field, which would require other functionality in order to implement properly.

Note that certain frameworks do support this.  For example, if your object derives from [`DependencyObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx), you could use [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Not the way you're describing. Extension methods are probably the closest you'll get.

```
public static class QueryExtensions
{
    public static bool HasMapping(this Demand role)
    {
        return role.DemandMappings.Count > 0;
    }
}
```

You would use the above example like this:

```
var role = GetDemand(Request.QueryString["id"]);
if (role != null)
{
    var mapped = role.HasMapping();
}
```

Comment: This is not closest. You're reading OP shows write to a property